# Book in which Calculus is explained in the form of a Teacher-Student Conversation

Tags: calculus, reference-request

I remember reading the preface of a Physics textbook in which the author mentions a book on Introductory Calculus in which the matter is explained in the form of an innovative conversation between a teacher and his student. I am eager to lay my hands on a copy of book as I think it is a very effective way of learning. Does anyone know what it's called?

Comment: Well, if you like manga there's [The Manga Guide to Calculus](http://www.amazon.com/Manga-Guide-Calculus-Hiroyuki-Kojima/dp/1593271948) :)

Comment: Not what you're asking for, but here's a video I once made where two friends discuss calculus: https://youtu.be/v_hq9pB4CnI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it, myself! It was: Caluclus: Basic Concepts For High Schools by LV Tarasov (1982). Though the convrsation is  not exactly between a teacher and his student but between the Author and the Reader. I can sleep peacefully today!

Answer (score 0):

Concepts, Problems and Solutions in School Calculus : A Dialogue Approach by Lev Tarasov and Chandra Shekhar Kumar ( ISBN-13 : 978-9354372926 )
[image]